# How to find repeat values in 4 different columns using SQL

Tags: sql

I wanted to find the last column mentioned in below image using SQL, any help?

[image]

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: Are you really looking for something in that **image**? Just count it up and you're done...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT UserName,
       Case WHEN Workflow1 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Workflow1,
       Case WHEN Workflow2 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Workflow2,
       Case WHEN Workflow3 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Workflow3,
       Case WHEN Workflow4 = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Workflow4 
FROM Table )

 SELECT UserName,
        Workflow1,
        Workflow2,
        Workflow3,
        Workflow4, 
        CAST (Workflow1 AS INT) + 
        CAST (Workflow2 AS INT) + 
        CAST (Workflow3 AS INT) + 
        CAST (Workflow4 AS INT) AS Count_Avail
 FROM CTE AS C
 INNER JOIN Table AS T ON C.UserName = T.UserName
```